# ALU, double and int

Tags: precision, alu

Sometimes, writing a code, situations such

```
 (double)Number1/(int)Number2     //division of a double type varible by a int one.
```

appears to me (and I think, to all of you more or less often) and I never knows what really happens if I rewrite (double) over (int).

```
    (double)Number1/(double)Number2
```

Is the performace the same? And the precision? And the time taken to perform it... Changes? Does the compiler, in general case (if it is possible to say such thing), write the same binary file. i. e., exe file? Does the called ALU operator chang?

I believe that a formal answer would depends on architecture of machine, compiler and language and a lot of stuff more. But... In these cases, how to have a notion about what would happen in "my code" and what choice would be better (if there is an appreciable difference)?

Thank you all for your replies!

Comment: What programming language? What are `Number1` and `Number2`? (Specifically, what types are they?)

Comment: Generally speaking, ALUs only work on operands of the same type - so if you're going to divide a `double`, the other operand is going to have to be converted to `double` as well, whether you explicitly write that in your code or not.

Comment: Jasonharper... That is what I want to know after all... So, generally, operands work with varible of the same type. I was wondering there would be a ALU operator for working witg Double and Int type (in a common computer), seeing that  such operation could be found in, peheaps, majority of codes involving statistical calculations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The precision can be different.

For example, if `Number2` is originally a `double`, converting it to an `int` with `(int)Number2` before the division can lose a lot of information both through truncating any bits after the binary point and by truncating any integral bits that don't fit in the `int`.

Comment: Yes! About that I don't doubt a point. I've done a umbiguous question. I don't want to focus on the casting, but on the operator in ALU. Working with (double) operator (double) is the same as doing with (double) operator (int)?

Comment: As far as I know on x86 at least, double precision division requires two `double`s, so with an `int` on the bottom, it has to convert it to a `double`. Having a `double` from the start avoids that step.

Comment: Such features I was asking for.. Thank you